# How to get page using nodejs that requires login

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

Is is even possible to get page that requires login using nodejs?

I don't know much about nodejs yet as I don't want to learn it if it can't do what I need.

I need to check one page once 10 minutes using server with Nodejs. That page requires login.
Is it possible to login with nodjs and keep all cookies so that "it" stays logged in?

This is how login looks like on page:
I send the username to the server, it responds with rsa-modulus and rsa-exponent
I encrypt the password using these given parameters and send username + password to the server for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Hooch,

how is the login implemented? Is it a form you're posting to, HTTP Basic?

Have a look at this [request module](https://github.com/mikeal/request) - it can fetch you a complete page and you can get/post anything you want.

If you gave us more input on how the login is realized, we could help you mich better.

Comment: It is post request with RSA key generated just before that post request. RSA key is used to send encrypted password in said post request.

Comment: |How can the client encrypt before sending to the server.. Thats not very logical Hooch.

Comment: If the client is a server-side script then this rsa value could be generated by the client as well.

Answer (score 0):

The http module can do this for you.. You will make your POST request to login and this retrieve the header.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  host: 'www. url to .com',
  port: 80,
  path: 'Route To Post To',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

REF: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.2/api/http.html#http.request

Comment: Ok. But how to "stay" logged in? So that after login I can do more requests to said page?

Comment: you would hold onto the session in some kind of singleton perhaps although it will only be for as long as the session you have requested will offer, better to use a callback function of some kind to see if you're still logged in.. This would be in the response header from the query of the server normally.

Comment: A lot of pages will send a session token back as a cookie, which you could save then include on subsequent requests.  You can check the response headers, or leverage something like https://www.npmjs.org/package/cookies to make it a bit easier.